# TAzureBlobService->GetBlob fails on big files

Tags: c++, azure, azure-functions, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm using TAzureBlobService->GetBlob(  ) to open text files in Azure. It fails on files over 100M; it fails after 30 seconds with "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally".
The files are fine, other apps (in other compilers) are happy.
Is there a size or time threshold with GetBlob()?

13 Mar ---

I've posted a little forms app (RAD Studio 10.2.3) that demonstrates the problem here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbywja0f6ss4o22/GetBlobTest.zip?dl=1
It contains the key to a test storage account with three test files (Test52M.txt, Test117M.txt, Test186M.txt).
The small one always succeeds, the middle one sometimes fails, the large one always fails.
Fails are always a touch over 30 secs, successes are always less than 30 sec.

The code just establishes a TAzureBlobService (key in the zip) and then the core code is:

```
// Create a MemoryStream for GetBlob to fill
if(MemoryStream) delete MemoryStream;
MemoryStream = new TMemoryStream();

try
{
    zUPairList props, metadata;
    Service->GetBlob(CtnrName, bname, L"", 0, 0, false, props, metadata, MemoryStream, CloudResponseInfo);
}
catch (Exception &exception)
{
    Result = exception.Message;
    return false;
}

Result = CloudResponseInfo->StatusMessage;
return true;
```

(zUPairList is a typedef for the long system pairlist classes)

The middle 117M sometimes fails, sometimes succeeds, so it's not a size issue.
All fails are a touch over 30 sec so it must be a time limit somewhere.

Comment: post the code reading blob.

Comment: Thanks for the note - see above for sample code etc.

Comment: man C++ has changed in the 10 years since I last coded in it! Just to be sure, is this C++?! Anyway, you should use the C++ SDK and download in chucks instead of whole 100MB at-once and in-memory.

Comment: Yes, C++ (Embacardero), and I don't have a choice about chunking. GetBlob is the only thing I've got to work, you give it a stream and it loads the lot. I have similar code in VisualStudio C++, also using GetBlob, also requiring a direct dump into memory (string this time) and it succeeds, going well beyond 30s with files 300M. I have similar code in VS C# and that does the tidy thing of providing a normal stream you can read form as you need. I just can't get it to go in RAD Studio (also tried 10.4)

Comment: If you're using C++ SDK, then perhaps you can see if it's setting any timeout in the underlying REST call using step-by-step debug. Also I stand by "don't read 100 MB at once" comment. [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-file-service-operations) tells you how to use range header when using the REST API. Find corresponding SDK function (or call REST API (which is not not straight forward as I would like)) and read in chunks with retries around each "chunk-read".

Comment: I'm not making the REST calls explicitly. I'm just calling Service->GetBlob() in the Azure API and expecting that to do all the chunking for me. The similar calls in VS C++ and C# do so but it looks like the RAD one is either not doing the right thing or there is some config I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the underlying HTTP connection is set up with various timeouts all equating to 60 seconds (see [this documentation page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.URLClient.TURLClient.ResponseTimeout) for an example of one of those defaults), the important one, the Azure timeout, has a default timeout of 30 seconds.

Therefore what your sample code is missing is something like this, where `Service` is your `TAzureService` reference:

```
Service->Timeout = 180;
```

Please refer to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Cloud.AzureAPI.TAzureService.Timeout) for further information.

Comment: One imagines the above VCL property maps onto [this REST API parameter in the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-blob-service-operations).

Comment: Thanks, Brian - that solves it - if it'd bin a snake it would have bit me.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it sounds like your connection may be having stability issues, since you are getting a termination rather than a returned error. You can see the rules for timeouts with GetBlob here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob

> A Get Blob operation is allowed 2 minutes per MiB to complete. If the operation is taking longer than 2 minutes per MiB on average, the operation will time out.

Comment: Thanks for the note - see above for sample code etc.